# Can external API endpoints be registered in Openstack Keystone service catalogue/registry?

Tags: api, openstack, api-gateway, keystone, openstack-keystone

We are developing few wrapper APIs (in SpringBoot and Python) on top of Openstack components like Nova, Neutron and glance.

As Keystone works as a service registry for internal Openstack APIs, is it possible to register our custom wrapper APIs in keystone registry? Basically, we want to use keystone as an API registry without having another API gateway.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: The keystone endoints are basically just URLs, so you can register anything. For example, if you want to use an external ceph rados gateway instead of deploying swift you can specify a swift endpoint pointing to the external ceph RGW.

Comment: Thanks @eblock for your inputs...can this be other way round like whether we can add new endpoints of custom apis in keystone instead of updating one (like swift endpoints as you mentioned)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know all the internals of keystone, maybe the [openstack-discuss mailing list](https://lists.openstack.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/openstack-discuss) is an additional place to ask this question.